# Java Execute methods from different project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, frameworks, cucumber

I am working on creating a framework that includes both capability to execute Selenium and Cucumber feature files. 
I will have the cucumber descriptions on my framework, and the AUT project and the framework will have a Maven dependency. 
The question is, can i execute the methods defined in the AUT project from my framework project?, my intention is to be able to execute an AUT method from the cucumber feature file. I will have a Keyword execution class to differentiate from framework keywords and AUT keywords.

Comment: Nobody is going to stop you trying :-).  But unless someone has already tried this, I doubt we can tell you whether it would work.

Comment: What do you mean by "executing a method" ? Calling a java method? Then there is no problem as long as you have set the dependency right. Those methods will better be packaged into the production (not test) artifact.

Comment: @MykolaGurov - What i mean is, creating a cucumber statement in which i specify to execute a method declared inside the AUT project, My idea is to be able to re-use the methods created inside the AUT proj; something like a login or a create user method, to avoid using cucumber statements individually for each webelement, which i have.

Comment: Cucumber statements should normally not be on the level of elements. They should be on the level of the user actions / feedback. Hence they will be specific to your project, and the AUT would rather provide internal functions for the project glue to use rather than the method to be mapped directly from the feature files. IMHO.